# How to seperate smoke volumetrics with mist?

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image][image]

How to separate mist from smoke in compositing? When rendering the smoke dissapears.

Comment: Could you please post a detailed screenshot of your node setup. It's currently very difficult to see what passes you are using.

Comment: Yes i have upload screenshot.my main gold is to have mist and smoke .for example mist like the render down and smoke like the viewport up all compine